# Google spreadsheet cell reference from value of another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

This is the scenario:

In cell A1 I have value "12".

In cell B1 I enter value "1".

In cell C1 I want to have value of Column "A" and row defined in cell B1.

How can I display the value "12"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`=INDIRECT("A"&B1)`

Help page for INDIRECT function: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093377?hl=en-GB

Comment: in case someone need above in range style:  =MIN(INDIRECT("Sheet4!$L$"&K2):INDIRECT("Sheet4!$L$"&L2)) that is equivalent to =MIN(Sheet4!$L$2:Sheet4!$L$48)) Or =MIN(Sheet4!$L$2:$L$48)) for K2= 2 and L2=48